# Can I give anti-rabies vaccine (PE Prophylaxis) to a 25-day-old puppy because he was bitten by a symptomatic rabid dog?

Tags: dogs, vaccination

I found a severely traumatized puppy in front of my home, two days ago. Brought her home and found two bite marks on the sides of her head. Upon asking around the locality, we realized she had been bitten by an aggressive dog the day before. The next day we found the perpetrator dog convulsing and dying in front of us. Some people say he died of rabies, some say he was hit on the head by a man that caused brain injury. We can never be too sure.

Now about this 25 day old puppy who has been bitten. Because the perpetrating dog has died, and that too showing symptoms of aggression and convulsion, we can't take a chance. One vet told she can't tolerate a post exposure prophylaxis course and die in a few days. Another told she can well tolerate it. The third one said she can only be administered 3 doses of 0 - 3 -7 and no more.

We also have an adult dog at home (vaccinated). Will he require a prophylaxis too because he sniffs the affected puppy and licks her urine?

What to do now? We administered her with one ARV 1ml SC yesterday (60 hrs after exposure), but will she die? She is ostensibly OK till now after 12 hours.I'm very much confused whether to continue the prophylaxis course or not give her anything due to high death risk by vaccine at such young age.

Please help.

[image]

Comment: I do not know the answer as to the vaccinations, but you need to absolutely keep that dog quarantined from your other animals, because it is possible to catch rabies without a bite wound, for instance, it is possible to become infected if saliva from the affected animal gets into an open wound or the mucous membrane, which can easily happen if the dog is say, licking you or your pets.  I would also recommend for your own safety, to get yourself rabies shots for this reason, and you should possibly get your pets re-vaccinated.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, Kai. Will our adult dog need a full course of post exposure prophylaxis or just one rabies shot? He is updated on vaccines and his yearly rabies shot is due in March.

Comment: That question should be answered by your vet.